# C++: stringstream parsing

Tags: c++, stringstream, istringstream

I am looking for an easy and elegant way for parsing numbers (dec and hex) with stringstream (or istringstream or some other Std-C++ class).

Valid input for a decimal number of e.g. 11 should be
11
0xb
bh

Normally I would use a regular expression but it is not possible here because of missing libraries and oder C++ compiler.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look at [std::strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

Answer (score 2):

It may be silly but IMHO simplest solution is `std::stringstream` + `std::hex` (and [others](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex))

```
unsigned int x;   
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << "0xb";
ss >> x;
```

Comment: I was thinking tooo complicated.

Comment: Doesn't work generically for the possible input defined by OP: `11 0xb bh`. It will set x to `17` for input `11`.

Comment: @zett42 My code is just an example for hex strings. I think `11 0xb bh` were just three possible inputs in three different number systems. In link that I posted there are manipulators for these systems. And from OP's comment to this answer I conclude that it helped him - and that was the goal.

Comment: My point is, simply setting `std::hex` is not enough to parse the possible kind of inputs *automatically*, you have to know in advance the numbering system for each input which kinda defeats the purpose. Btw, `bh` is just a different notation for `0xb`, which can't be parsed using `std::hex` or any of the other linked manipulators.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but I think that the default `istream::operator >>` is not able to detect base automatically from the input. The manipulator `std::hex` can only be used to *force* the base to 16 but it will be applied to all input without regard for prefix "0x" or suffix "h".

We can work around by overloading `operator >>` for a custom type and call `std::stoi()`:

```
struct ParsedInt
{
    int val;
};

inline std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& strm, ParsedInt& i )
{
    std::string s; strm >> s;
    i.val = 0;

    if( ! s.empty() )
    {
        if( s.back() == 'h' )
            // explicitly use base 16 to parse hex
            i.val = static_cast<int>( std::stoul( s, nullptr, 16 ) );
        else
            // stoi() with base 0 will detect prefix "0x".
            i.val = static_cast<int>( std::stoul( s, nullptr, 0 ) );
    }

    return strm;
}
```

Usage example:

```
int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss( "11 0xb bh -11 0xffffffff fffffffeh" );

    ParsedInt i;
    while( ss >> i )
    {
        std::cout << i.val << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11
11    
11    
-11    
-1    
-2
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f3f639d18d29c75).

**Edit:**

Original code crashed with `std::out_of_range` exceptions for negative hex numbers like `0xFFFFFFFF`, this has been fixed by replacing `std::stoi()` with `std::stoul()` and `static_cast`ing the result to `int`.